# How to get proper data from ImmutableDict

Tags: jquery, python, post, flask, werkzeug

On my html I have script that creates form in a modal, from table. I have there text as well as file, so data is "multipart/form-data"

```
var modalForm = $('<form role="form" name="modalForm" action="/admin/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>');
```

In my flask, I'm getting POST back with:

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import CombinedMultiDict, ImmutableMultiDict
imd = ImmutableMultiDict(request.form)
```

and I receive :

> ImmutableMultiDict([('username', u'John'), ('email', u'john@snow.com')])

Which is weird for me - why i receive it as a immutableMultiDict, why it's not processed? but ok.
Now If I would do:

```
for i in imd.itervalues():
   print i
```

I would get:

> John
>
> john@snow.com

Awesome! BUT why if I ask for

```
imd['username']
```

or

```
imd.get('username')
```

I am getting with unicode string

> u'John'
>   sure, I could fix that with str(imd['username']) but I haven't seen anyone else doing so within examples on internet. What might be wrong ?

When I have tried

```
CombinedMultiDict((request.files, request.form))
```

I received:

> CombinedMultiDict((ImmutableMultiDict([('avatar', )]), ImmutableMultiDict([('username', u'John'), ('email', u'John@snow.com')])))

Comment: thanks! now I understand what it stands for, but should I get that prefix as a value of dict key ?

Comment: If you do `print u'John'` it will print correctly. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. BTW, proper Unicode handling is a lot saner in Python 3.